# Pass component instance directly into prop or use a render callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What would be the idiomatic and/or more effective way of handling a situation whereby the parent component wants the child to render some custom JSX?

- a render callback?
- or passing a component instance directly into the prop?

Example:

```
// Option 1
// -
const rightChild = <View />

<NavigationBar rightChild={rightChild} />

// Option 2
// -
const renderRightChild = () => <View />

<NavigationBar renderRightChild={rightChild}>
```

(lambdas are used for simplicity, I am aware of the performance implications)

Answer (score 2):

This:

> ```
> const rightChild = <View />
> // ...
> <NavigationBar rightChild={rightChild} />
> ```

...isn't "passing JSX into the prop." It's passing a component instance. The JSX is processed by `const rightChild = <View />` (turned into `React.createElement` call) and the *result* (a component instance) is stored in `rightChild`. That's normal, though it's usually as a child (ending up on the `children` prop) rather than a separate named prop. But either way, it's a prop, so...

As far as I know, that would be the standard way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the terminological correction, I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 1):

Either way will work. The case for when you really want to use a render prop is when you will need the props passed from NavigationBar in order to render the component or fragment. The benefit to passing in a component is that you will not be passing in a new function to be rendered each time. From a performance standpoint it would be a bit easier to get it to not for a re-render.